# reactjs formData upload file

Tags: reactjs, axios, form-data

> hi there
> I have a problem with react js,
> I have an upload file and want to send
> this file by form data into backend , this is my code :

```
      for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
          const rand = uuidv4()
          const form = new FormData();
          form.append('TicketId', inFuncResult);
          form.append('Title', title);
          form.append('Description', body);
          form.append('LatinCode', 'ldj3556');
          form.append('file',  JSON.stringify(selectedFiles[i]));
          // form.append("file", new Blob([selectedFiles[i]], {type: 'application/octet-stream'}));
          form.append('fileType', 'Warranty');
          form.append('Id', rand);
          const myForm = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(form));
          await TicketFileAPI.post(
            "/TicketFile",
            form,
          );
        }
```

> But when I submit this data, an error occurs because the file form data is sent as an empty object '{}'. This is my submit model:

```
{"TicketId":"2ca3c87d-65d4-ed11-afe9-e4fd45c4a1fc","Title":"wqe","Description":"sadasd","LatinCode":"ldj3556","file":{},"fileType":"Warranty","Id":"13602769-5dab-4033-81a2-cc7b20f13459"}
```

can u tell me what is the my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `JSON.stringify` from the file append. Like this:

```
form.append('file',  selectedFiles[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line const myForm = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(form)); and send the form object directly in your axios request as follows:

```
await TicketFileAPI.post(
    "/TicketFile",
    form
);
```